# How do I delete a D3 tree node using code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, d3.js

I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Deansmithok/3HeU9/

I would like to delete a node (and it's links)

On my last attempt:

I have saved the the d.id in the DOM as $('#inpSelidTAUsers').val()
then tried this code...

```
svgGroup.selectAll('path.link').filter(function(d, i)
  {
  if (d.target.id == $('#inpSelidTAUsers').val() ) 
    return true; else return false;
  }).remove();

svgGroup.selectAll('g.node').data(nodes).filter(function(d, i)
  { 
  if (d.id == $('#inpSelidTAUsers').val()) 
    return true; else return false; 
  }).remove();
```

This code does remove the node and link on the screen. But if I call DrawItAll(root) then the node RE-APPEARS. Please tell me how I can delete the node so that It stays GONE :)

Comment: Well, you are removing the node and link from the d3 selection but not from the data. So, once you render the data again, it will show up. Or am I missing something?

Comment: And of course I mean the datum representing the node and link. You would need to remove that from the dataset.

Comment: Hi. You are right - I am not updating the dataset... just I don't know how to do that. I cannot see how to access the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selection returns the element g.node, and although you removed it from the view, it appears you rebind it, unhanged. Since you aren't changing the underlying data, when you rebind it you'll get the same thing you got the first time.

If you want the node gone you need to change the dataset. Your data is in this object:

```
treeData = {
  'name': 'Me','POS':'CEO','children':
    [
    {'name': 'Mr X','POS':'Sales Manager'},
    {'name': 'Mr Y','POS':'Architect'},
    {'name': 'Mr Z','POS':'Finance Assistant','children':[{'name': 'Mr U','POS':'Window Cleaner'}]},
    ]
  };
```

The cleanest way to be able to remove children nodes from treeData is probably to add a function like this to the object:

```
treeData.removeChild = function(idxToRemove) {
  var i, len, results;
  results = [];
  for (i = 0, len = this.children.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i !== idxToRemove) {
      results.push(treeData.children[i]);
    }
  }
  this.children = results;
};
```

Then you'd just call the index of the element you want to remove as such:

```
treeData.removeChild(2)  // removes the last child
```

Then rebind the data and update the view.

Comment: Hi. This worked. It was 'treeData' or 'root' that I had to work with.  Thanks